# How to get textbox value and set it to a variable in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I try to attempt a connection to a postgressl database. I have few textboxes to ask user details as ip address, database name etc...

My problem occures when I try to set to a variable textbox value.
The error message is : `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

After some reading online I know I encounter this error because I try to use something that is null. I use a reference that is not initialized
(It's my first time coding in VB so I know I miss something). I don't understand why I get this error.

The debugger is showing me the error occures here : `Dim user As String = TextBox1.Text` . 
So it means `TextBox1.Text` is returning something null, isn't it ? Or am I using a wrong method to get textbox value ?

```
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class UserControl1
    Dim myConnection As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Dim user As String = TextBox1.Text, password As String = TextBox2.Text, ipServ As String = TextBox3.Text, dbName As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim selectRequest As String, crudRequest As String
    Dim erreur As Boolean
    Dim driver As String = "{PostgreSQL Unicode}", port As Integer = 5432, pooling As String = "True", minPoolSize As Integer = 0, maxPoolSize As Integer = 100, coLifetime As Integer = 0
    Dim cString As String = "Driver=" & driver & ";Uid=" & user & ";Pwd=" & password & ";Server=" & ipServ & ";Port=" & port & ";Database=" & dbName & ";Pooling=" & pooling & ";Min Pool Size=" & minPoolSize & ";Max Pool Size=" & maxPoolSize & ";Connection Lifetime=" & coLifetime & ";"


    Sub connexion_base_odbc(ByRef myConnection, ByVal cString, ByRef erreur)

        'Ouvre une connection vers une base de données ODBC

        'cString = "Driver=" & driver & ";Uid=" & user & ";Pwd=" & password & ";Server=" & ipServ & ";Port=" & port & ";Database=" & dbName & ";Pooling=" & pooling & ";Min Pool Size=" & minPoolSize & ";Max Pool Size=" & maxPoolSize & ";Connection Lifetime=" & coLifetime & ";"

        Try
            myConnection.ConnectionString = cString
            myConnection.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connexion réussie !")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Problème lors de la connection à la base. " & ex.Message)
            erreur = True
            Exit Sub
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call connexion_base_odbc(myConnection, cString, erreur)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: It is not quite `So it means TextBox1.Text is returning something null` - It is very much likely that `TextBox1` hasn't been initialised. You should move the majority of those class level variables to be inside the sub `connexion_base_odbc`

Comment: @JayV Why to move this variables inside the sub will initialise `TextBox1` ?

Comment: With VB.Net there is a function that you do not normally see called `InitializeComponent` It is called from the default constructor (`Sub New()`) that you also, normally, don't see unless you need to do specific initialisations in the constructor. Assigning values to Class Level variables when they are declared will cause those lines of code to be executed before the Constructor (and the InitializeComponent) and therefore before the `TextBox1` has been initialised

Comment: @JayV I see, my problem was simple to fix. I moved as you suggested and I don't have this error anymore. Now I know a bit more about VB.Net, and your explanations make senses. Thank you !

Answer (score -2):

**hmmm sorry guys, I think this problem is related to writing user control in the correct way.**

- register user control properly in VB
  https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/asp.net-usercontrol-by-vb.net
- user control has multiple instances that running simultaneity so call its control with correct prefix probably in your case: this.textbox
  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/194856/control-values-of-a-usercontrol-are-always-returni
- you should using control after initializing, so read an article about the page life cycle and call control in the correct way.